# Node.js: Multiple then's not executing in the correct order

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I am *very* new to NodeJS, and I am trying to use promises to prompt the user for input in a specific order. Here is my code:

```
var prompt = require('prompt');
var promising = require("promise-adapter");

var promptGet = promising(prompt.get);

prompt.start();

function Game () {
    playerOneName = '';
    playerTwoName = '';
    pOneType = true; 
}

//prompts the user for two names and assigns them 
//to player one and player to for the game object
Game.prototype.getName = function (resolve){
    promptGet(['playerName1', 'playerName2']).then(function(result){
        this.playerOneName = result.playerName1;
        this.playerTwoName = result.playerName2;
    })
    .then(function() {
        resolve();
    });
}

Game.prototype.getType = function (resolve) {
    //console.log('made it to the function');
    promptGet(['Player1Type']).then(function(result){
        if (result.Player1Type !== "X"){ this.pOneType = false;}
        //console.log(this.pOneType);
    })
    .then(function(){
        resolve();
    });
}
Game.prototype.displayPlayers = function(resolve) {
    if (pOneType === true){
        console.log(this.playerOneName + " will be X's");
        console.log(this.playerTwoName + " will be O's");
    }
    else {
        console.log(this.playerOneName + " will be O's");
        console.log(this.playerTwoName + " will be X's");
    } 
    console.log("Let's Get Started!");
}

var test = new Game();

new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        test.getName(resolve);
    })
    .then(function(resolve, reject){
        test.getType();
    })
    .then(function(resolve, reject){
        test.displayPlayers();
    });
```

I know that this is very sloppy code, but even so, I think that it should work such that the test.displayPlayers() executes *before* test.getType(), but it is not. Thanks for any help! I am also willing to hear advice about how to clean up the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't say that promises is the way to do this, but if you still want to use it, you've misunderstood how to use them for the task at hand.

Each *asynchronous* code block should return a promise, and in your case those would be the blocking while waiting for the user inputs.

You define functions that return either a new promise or an existing promise and chain them onto each other, thus being able to control the execution order of your code.

Take a look at the simple fiddle below. Note that `getName` returns a new promise, which is constructed using the `Promise` constructor that takes an executor as parameter, that supplies the `resolve` and `reject` functions of the promise implementation.

When your asynchronous code is done, or in this case the blocking code, you simply resolve the promise with or without a resolved value.

By default, the `.then()` function returns a new promise, and if you return an object inside the `.then()` function, it will be automatically resolved, unless the object is a new promise.

```js
function Game() {
  var playerOneName = '';
  var playerTwoName = '';
  var pOneType = true;
}

//prompts the user for two names and assigns them 
//to player one and player to for the game object
Game.prototype.getName = function(resolve) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var playerOneName = prompt("Please enter your name", "Harry Potter");
    var playerTwoName = prompt("Please enter your name", "Ron Weasley");
    if (playerOneName !== null && playerTwoName !== null) {
      resolve();
    } else {
      reject();
    }
  });
}

var someOtherFunction = function() {
  alert("This is inside some other function!");
  return "A value that gets resolved by the promise!";
}


var testGame = new Game();
testGame.getName()
  .then(function() {
    alert("This happens when names have been chosen!");
  })
  .then(someOtherFunction)
  .then(function(resolvedValue) {
    alert(resolvedValue);
  })
```

From this you should be able to get the basic stuff of promises, but I highly recommend that you read the [MDN Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) documentation.

Answer (score 2):

you cannot depend on `then` to execute code in a specific order, `then` is an asynchronous function.
if you wish to make a series of promises execute in a specific order take a look at [Async.js](https://github.com/caolan/async). it will go something like this:

```
async.series([
    function(){ ... },
    function(){ ... }
]);
```

Comment: Okay, I definitely will, but I thought the whole point of then was to wait until the previous then was completed before the next one is executed?

Comment: think of then as running multiple threads as the same time, sure you get to start which which thread to go first, but other threads do not have to wait for each other to begin execution

Answer (score 0):

I don't see your problem, for me a promise work like a event.

If you realy want execute test.displayPlayers() after test.getType(); do something like that :

```js
var prompt = require('prompt');
var promising = require("promise-adapter");

var promptGet = promising(prompt.get);

prompt.start();

function Game () {
    playerOneName = '';
    playerTwoName = '';
    pOneType = true; 
}

//prompts the user for two names and assigns them 
//to player one and player to for the game object
Game.prototype.getName = function (resolve){
    promptGet(['playerName1', 'playerName2']).then(function(result){
        this.playerOneName = result.playerName1;
        this.playerTwoName = result.playerName2;
    })
    .then(function() {
        resolve();
    });
}

Game.prototype.getType = function (resolve) {
    //console.log('made it to the function');
    promptGet(['Player1Type']).then(function(result){
        if (result.Player1Type !== "X"){ this.pOneType = false;}
        //console.log(this.pOneType);
    })
    .then(function(){
        resolve();
    });
}
Game.prototype.displayPlayers = function(resolve) {
    if (pOneType === true){
        console.log(this.playerOneName + " will be X's");
        console.log(this.playerTwoName + " will be O's");
    }
    else {
        console.log(this.playerOneName + " will be O's");
        console.log(this.playerTwoName + " will be X's");
    } 
    console.log("Let's Get Started!");
}

var test = new Game();

new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        test.getName(resolve);
    })
    .then(function(resolve, reject){
        test.getType();
        test.displayPlayers();
    })
```

Comment: But when I do this, displayPlayers() is executed before the getType() has had a chance to run, resulting in an undefined output.